# Why does the footprint change when I add it to the schematic?

Tags: eaglecad, footprint

I am using "FTSH-105-01-L-D-K" in my PCB design. When I check the footprint of this component directly through library, I can see that there is enough clearance between the pads (please refer img. "footprints.png", the right picture shows the footprint from the library, you can see roughly 3-4 squares in each pad at 0.05mm grid) but when I add it in my schematic diagram and convert to board, the clearance reduces and seems like the diameter of pads increase (please refer img. "footprint.png", the picture on left is when that component is added in board, you can see the clearance has reduced and the pad can now fit 5-6 squares at same-0.05 mm grid). I don't understand how is it happening, can someone please help. Thanks!  [image]

Comment: Is there more than one footprint associated with the component in the library?

Comment: The minimum annular ring is changed in the design rules.

Comment: @mkeith, no it is not, but I got what I should be looking at. I'll post answer to my question, thanks!

Comment: @Jeroen3, Yes I got it free of error now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I was missing. For someone, who faces the same issue...it is related to annular ring size as @Jeroen mentioned.
The pads' annular ring size depends on your DRC settings. For that, go to DRC -> Annular Rings and either lower the % if you want them smaller or the max/min parameters. However, it is important to consult with your PCB manufacturer for final changes. For more info:
[From Autodesk](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-restring/)